# Issue in importing package in reactjs project

Tags: reactjs, json

I am trying to import the package in my reactjs application, but I am getting an error in the path. Unfortunately, I can not copy the whole copy. Will you please suggest a solution?

[image]

Comment: Why is there src .(dot)

Comment: react packages can also be got as ../components/Forms/forms

Comment: @AnkitTale I am still getting the error with ../components/Forms/forms the module not found, did you mean the path without inverted comma?

Comment: Why is it 'src./components/Forms/Form', shouldn't it be './src/components/Forms/Form'?